# XYDotRenderer tooltip not working

Tags: java, tooltip, jfreechart

I am plotting using JFreeChart. By default the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` can display tooltips. If I change it to a `XYDotRenderer`, the tooltips disappear. Am I missing anything? Here is the code snippet

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
    "Test Prices","time","price",dataset,true,true,false);

XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
XYDotRenderer renderer = new XYDotRenderer();
renderer.setDotHeight(10);
renderer.setDotWidth(10);
renderer.setLegendItemToolTipGenerator(
    new StandardXYSeriesLabelGenerator("ToolTip {0}"));
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your snippet whether you want item tooltips or legend tooltips; I will address both:

- Unlike `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, `XYDotRenderer` does not include support for chart entities, which is required for item tooltips.
- Legend tooltips work correctly.

  ```
  XYSeriesLabelGenerator legendGenerator = new StandardXYSeriesLabelGenerator();
  renderer.setLegendItemToolTipGenerator(legendGenerator);
  ```